# How to while loop in Powershell were it reads the content in a file?

Tags: python, file, while-loop

I can't find much documentation on this, but if we wanted to create a while loop, where it reads the content (from each line) in a file and passes that value into an executable command.

So the example is that I use PowerShell terminal to run a python script. The script requires parameters to be provided. One of the parameters to be provided is filenames. However, I'd like to write these filenames, as a list, into a document. Then use a PowerShell while loop to read each line of the document and push it to the executable command.

Is that possible?

This is the command I am running at the moment:

```
python .\retrieve_files.py -filename "filename1" "filename2" "filename3"
```

This isn't sufficient however if I have over 100 files to retrieve.

Comment: In the example you've posted you're passing 3 file names to `python` - do you want to do the same here, buffering 3 items before invoking the python script once? "This isn't sufficient however if I have over 100 files to retrieve." - because of limitations to how many files the python script can process at once? Or because you don't want to manually write out a 1000-char command line? :)

Comment: I am hoping I can create a document that has the filenames in an array/list e.g.
filename1
filename2
filename3
filename4
filename5
filename6
etc.
Then the while loop looks at each line and passes it to the executable command that I provided above.

Comment: Right, but then you want to read it back from disk and process each in a while loop. What should happen in the while loop body? `python .\retrieve_files.py -filename "<one_file_name_at_a_time>"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can read filenames in specific directory using `os`. Just specify path to the directory.

```
import os


filenames_list = []
for file in os.listdir('path'):
    filenames_list.append(file)
    
output = 'filenames.txt'


with open(output, 'w') as f:
    for filename in filenames_list:
        f.write(filename + ',\n')
```

Comment: Thank you @forest-spells, but how do I incorporate my python script into your description?

Comment: Ahh apologies, you have given me a python script here. Correct?

Comment: yes, just replace 'path' with yours and run it once - it will create a .txt file